# Can't access /outlook/masterCategories endpoint in Microsoft Graph's API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

It seems any endpoints starting starting with `/outlook` return this error:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/outlook/masterCategories
{
    "error": {
        "code": "RequestBroker-ParseUri",
        "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'Outlook'.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "a75d1c9a-c6ae-4b69-83ca-fc0e467a4ad7",
            "date": "2017-12-26T17:23:17"
        }
    }
}
```

I have authorized the scopes `mail.read` `user.read` `mailboxsettings.readwrite` so I should be able to access a user's inbox categories, but the beta API endpoints starting with "outlook" mentioned in this post:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2017/10/09/new-outlook-apis-in-the-microsoft-graph-rooms-rules-categories-headers-and-time-zones/

are not accessible whatsoever, am I doing something wrong?

Keep in mind I tested this endpoint and it works perfectly: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/mailFolders

but this one: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/outlook/masterCategories returns the error above.

Comment: Is this an O365/Exchange or a personal outlook.com mailbox?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur personal

Answer (score 6):

I'm afraid the `/beta` documentation is a bit ahead of the `/beta` code itself. Currently the `beta/me/outlook/` endpoints (including `/masterCategories`) do not support MSA/Personal accounts.

I've been unable to definitively confirm if/when support is forthcoming (not all that surprising given the time of year), so I'm afraid I don't have an ETA on when this might roll out.

Comment: Thanks Marc for the clarification - I was incredibly confused by the error! we're building an integration for Outlook and categorization is an essential feature for us - could you possibly update this answer when you get a response? i'd highly appreciate it! (i'm sure others would be too)